# A rearrangement integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ be a positive function, show that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}|x|^{2}f(x)dx\geq \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}|x|^{2}f^{*}(x)dx, $$
where $f^{*}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\chi_{\{|f(x)|>t\}^{*}}(x)dt$ denotes the symmetric decreasing rearrangement of $f(x)$.

I am trying to use
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}|x|^{2}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}|x|^{2}\chi_{\{|f(x)|>t\}}(x)dx  \right)dt$$
and
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}|x|^{2}f^{*}(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}|x|^{2}\chi_{\{|f(x)|>t\}^{*}}(x)dx  \right)dt$$

But it seems not work. Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you see the inequality in some book or paper? Is it really true ? If so, please, tell me the reference.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{\mathbb R}|x|^2f(x)\,\mathrm d x=\int_{\mathbb R}|x|^2\int_0^{|f(x)|}\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d x=\int_{\mathbb R}|x|^2f^*(x)\,\mathrm d x.$$

Comment: Why the second equality hold？ Can you give more details ？

Comment: because $\int_a^bdx=b-a$ and $f(x)>0$. @pxchg1200

Comment: But $f^{*}$ is the rearrangement of $f$, how can you deduce that $\int_{\mathbb R}|x|^2\int_0^{|f(x)|}\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d x=\int_{\mathbb R}|x|^2f^*(x)\,\mathrm d x.$ ?

Comment: $\int_0^{|f(x)|}dt=\int_0^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{\{|f(x)|>t\}}\,\mathrm d t=f^*(x)$. @pxchg1200

Comment: @Surb, did you mean $\int_0^{|f(x)|} dt = \int_0^{\infty} \textbf{1}_{\{|f| > t\}^{\ast}}$ ? By definition, it is not true that $f^\ast (x) = \int_0^{\infty} \textbf{1}_{\{|f| > t\}} dt$.